# Problem when inserting an image

Tags: graphics

I have to insert an image in a document but there are some troubles. I drew the picture using the geogebra software and I exported it as PSTricks. Geogebra generated the following script and it works when compiled with XeLaTex but I have to insert this script in another file to be compiled with pdfLatex and it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newrgbcolor{qqwuqq}{0. 0.39 0.}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6.76,-1.82)(3.85,4.54)
\multips(0,-1)(0,0.25){26}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecap=1,dash=1.5pt 1.5pt,linewidth=0.4pt,linecolor=lightgray]{c-c}(-6.76,0)(3.85,0)}
\multips(-6,0)(0.25,0){43}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecap=1,dash=1.5pt 1.5pt,linewidth=0.4pt,linecolor=lightgray]{c-c}(0,-1.82)(0,4.54)}
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=false,yAxis=true,labels=y,Dx=1.,Dy=1.,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-6.76,-1.82)(3.85,4.54)
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.2pt,fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.10](-4.25,0.75)(-3.75,0.75)(-3.75,1.25)(-3.25,1.25)(-3.25,1.75)(-2.75,1.75)(-2.75,2.25)(-2.25,2.25)(-2.25,2.75)(-1.75,2.75)(-1.75,3.25)(-1.25,3.25)(-1.25,3.75)(-0.75,3.75)(-0.25,3.75)(-0.25,4.25)(-4.75,4.25)(-4.75,3.75)(-4.25,3.75)
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.2pt,fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.10](-5.25,4.5)(0.75,4.5)(-4.242,0.07)
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.2pt,fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.10](-4.24,0.07)(2.04,0.08)(0.75,4.5)
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.2pt,fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.10](0.75,3.75)(0.75,2.25)(1.25,2.25)(1.25,0.75)(1.75,0.75)(1.75,0.25)(-3.25,0.25)(-3.25,0.75)(-2.75,0.75)(-2.75,1.25)(-2.25,1.25)(-2.25,1.75)(-1.75,1.75)(-1.25,1.75)(-1.25,2.25)(-0.75,2.25)(-0.75,2.75)(-0.25,2.75)(-0.25,3.25)(0.25,3.25)(0.25,3.75)
\rput[tl](-3.44,4.03){$Q^{\epsilon}_j$}
\rput[tl](-0.004,4.56){$Q_j$}
\rput[tl](0.21,4.24){$Q_{j+1}$}
\rput[tl](-0.83,2.05){$Q^{\epsilon}_{j+1}$}
\rput[tl](-4.15,-2.86){$B^\epsilon=\epsilon B$}
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-4.25,0.75)(-3.75,0.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-3.75,0.75)(-3.75,1.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-3.75,1.25)(-3.25,1.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-3.25,1.25)(-3.25,1.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-3.25,1.75)(-2.75,1.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.75,1.75)(-2.75,2.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.75,2.25)(-2.25,2.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.25,2.25)(-2.25,2.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.25,2.75)(-1.75,2.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.75,2.75)(-1.75,3.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.75,3.25)(-1.25,3.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.25,3.25)(-1.25,3.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.25,3.75)(-0.75,3.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-0.75,3.75)(-0.25,3.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-0.25,3.75)(-0.25,4.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-0.25,4.25)(-4.75,4.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-4.75,4.25)(-4.75,3.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-4.75,3.75)(-4.25,3.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-4.25,3.75)(-4.25,0.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-5.25,4.5)(0.75,4.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0.75,4.5)(-4.24,0.07)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-4.24,0.07)(-5.25,4.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-4.24,0.07)(2.04,0.08)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](2.04,0.08)(0.75,4.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0.75,4.5)(-4.24,0.07)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0.75,3.75)(0.75,2.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0.75,2.25)(1.25,2.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](1.25,2.25)(1.25,0.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](1.25,0.75)(1.75,0.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](1.75,0.75)(1.75,0.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](1.75,0.25)(-3.25,0.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-3.25,0.25)(-3.25,0.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-3.25,0.75)(-2.75,0.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.75,0.75)(-2.75,1.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.75,1.25)(-2.25,1.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.25,1.25)(-2.25,1.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2.25,1.75)(-1.75,1.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.75,1.75)(-1.25,1.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.25,1.75)(-1.25,2.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-1.25,2.25)(-0.75,2.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-0.75,2.25)(-0.75,2.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-0.75,2.75)(-0.25,2.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-0.25,2.75)(-0.25,3.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-0.25,3.25)(0.25,3.25)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0.25,3.25)(0.25,3.75)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0.25,3.75)(0.75,3.75)
\rput[tl](1.64,-1.39){$\epsilon$}
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{->}(-4.03,-2.86)(-4.5,-2.)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{->}(-4.03,-2.86)(-4.,-2.)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{->}(-4.03,-2.86)(-3.5,-2.)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{->}(1.5,-2.)(1.5,-1.5)
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt]{->}(1.5,-1.5)(1.5,-2.)
\begin{scriptsize}
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,-2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,-1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,-1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,-0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,0.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,0.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,1.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,1.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,2.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,2.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,3.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,3.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,4.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,4.5)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-6.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-5.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-4.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-3.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-2.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-1.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](-0.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](0.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](1.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](2.5,5.)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=qqwuqq](3.,5.)
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

The main file is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,leqno]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\include{immagine}

\end{document}
```

the file "immagine" contains the script exept first 4 lines and the last one. When compiled with pdfLatex the editor gives the following error:

! Undefined control sequence.
 \c@lor@to@ps

l.5 ...linecolor=lightgray]{c-c}(-6.76,0)(3.85,0)}

I can't understand where's the mistake...my latex software is for Mac and I use the TexWorks editor version 0.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exported the image as `PSTricks`, which (I believe) has to be compiled with XeLaTeX. Instead, have you considered exporting the image as `PGF/Tikz`? You will need to use `pgf` and/or `tikz` packages. If that's not also an option for you, you may consider exporting the image as `.eps` directly from geogebra.

Comment: Unfortunately exporting the image as .eps omits some details (hides the grid of points in correspondence of the polygons). On the other hand, compiling as XeLaTeX gives other problems related with the texts. this is the error:! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:èin not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: What about pgf/tikz? Maybe my previous answer sounds misleading and leads you to think pgf/tikz needs XeLaTeX which does not. Try exporting as pgf/tikz

Comment: ok, thanks, I managed to insert the image as pgf/tikz but this environment does not permit to use the package utf8. Anyway, this does not seem to affect the other parts of the document. Is there any way to overcome this conflict?

Comment: No, sorry I'm wrong, it works!

Comment: How did it go? Did I solve your problem?

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as accepted, clicking the tick at the left